# Twitter API v1.1 Error: Limited Access (453)

Tags: go, twitter

Currently i am working on a go project: tweets on twitter with text received from chatgpt every 10 minutes.And i have a problem with twitter api. I am  using free plan of twitter and it says you have access for tweeting in this plan.

```
package twitter

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/dghubble/go-twitter/twitter"
    "github.com/dghubble/oauth1"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type Credentials struct {
    consumerKey        string
    consumerSecret     string
    accessToken       string
    accessTokenSecret string
}

func Tweet() {
    credentials := fetchTwitterConfig()
    config := oauth1.NewConfig(credentials.consumerKey, credentials.consumerSecret)
    token := oauth1.NewToken(credentials.accessToken, credentials.accessTokenSecret)

    httpClient := config.Client(oauth1.NoContext, token)

    client := twitter.NewClient(httpClient)

    verifyParams := &twitter.AccountVerifyParams{
        SkipStatus:  twitter.Bool(true),
        IncludeEmail: twitter.Bool(true),
    }
    _, _, err := client.Accounts.VerifyCredentials(verifyParams)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Verifying credentials error:\n%s", err)
        return
    }
    _, _, err = client.Statuses.Update("Test", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Tweeting error\n%s", err)
    }
}

func fetchTwitterConfig() *Credentials {
    configPath, err := getConfigPath()
    if err != nil {
        handleError("Error getting absolute path", err)
        return nil
    }

    viper.SetConfigFile(configPath)
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        handleError("Error reading configuration", err)
        return nil
    }

    return &Credentials{
        consumerKey:        getStringFromConfig("twitter.consumer-key"),
        consumerSecret:     getStringFromConfig("twitter.consumer-secret"),
        accessToken:       getStringFromConfig("twitter.access-token"),
        accessTokenSecret: getStringFromConfig("twitter.access-token-secret"),
    }
}

func getConfigPath() (string, error) {
    configPath, err := filepath.Abs("./config/config.yml")
    return configPath, err
}

func handleError(message string, err error) {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", message, err)
}

func getStringFromConfig(key string) string {
    value := viper.GetString(key)
    if value == "" {
        fmt.Printf("%s property is not set in the configuration\n", key)
    }
    return value
}
```

i fetch env vars from a yml file with viper. And this is my main.go file

```
import (
    "github.com/ibomoko/twitter-gpt-go/twitter"
)

func  main() {
    twitter.Tweet()
}
```

I am getting this message

***Tweeting error
twitter: 453 You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you
may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product***

I tried different authentication methods but it doesnt work in my case.